# Converting int to Char* giving ascii values C++

Tags: c++, int, chars

hi im trying to intialize a variable 
im calling it

```
int Score;
char Buffer[1024];
```

im using SDL so to display them i had to convert Score to char

With this im incrementing the score

```
                case SDLK_m:
                    Score+=1;
                    break;
```

and im displaying this with this function

```
void GetText()
{
    itoa (Score,Buffer,1024);

    drawString(screen,font2,0,0,"Score: ");
    drawString(screen,font2,50,0,Buffer);
}
```

so when im displaying it it goes like this
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,etc
and i want it to normally count like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,etc

so what am i doing wrong? any idea?

Comment: The third parameter of `itoa` is the *base*. You want base 10, not base 1024.

Answer (score 3):

itoa is defined as follows: `char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );`

The last param is the base, not the buffer size, so in your case you would want to pass in `10` as follows:

```
itoa(Score, Buffer, 10);
```